# How to set value of argument using python callback for C program

Tags: python, c

My Python code, there is a callback function for C:

```
global cbGetIMSI
CB_GET_IMSI  = CFUNCTYPE(None, c_char_p)
cbGetIMSI   = CB_GET_IMSI(py_getIMSI)
def py_getIMSI(imsi):
    global tc
    tc  = import(mod)
    imsi = tc.getIMSI()
    print '####### imsi = ' + imsi
```

and call C function to register:

```
lib_inf = cdll.LoadLibrary(self.libinf.get())
lib_inf.inf_regCbGetImsi(cbGetIMSI)
```

My C Code:

```
typedef void (*inf_PyCbGetImsi)(char *);
int inf_regCbGetImsi(inf_PyCbGetImsi cbFn)
{
    DBG("enter [%s()]", FUNCTION);
    if (!cbFn)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    g_pyCB.getImsi = cbFn;
    return 0;
}

static int GetIMSI()
{
    int ret = 0;
    int i = 0;
    unsigned char aIMSI[15];
    DBG("[enter %s()]", __FUNCTION__);

    memset(aIMSI, 0, sizeof(aIMSI));
    if (g_pyCB.getImsi)
    {
        g_pyCB.getImsi(aIMSI);

    }
    DBG("[%s()] aIMSI = [%s]", __FUNCTION__, aIMSI);  

    return ret;
}
```

Run log in Python:

```
####### imsi = 001010123456789
in C Program:
[GetIMSI()] aIMSI = []
```

Why has the value of the argument not changed, and how would I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: it is not NULL ,otherwise py_getIMSI cannot be excuted.Thanks.

Comment: def getIMSI():
    return '001010123456789'

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your line:

```
imsi = tc.getIMSI()
```

Here you don't *set* the value of `imsi`, you just re-define it as another "something", which is a behaviour you would have in C too.

If you want to set the value of `imsi`, you should *copy* the value in it by using something like `strcpy`, which is usable by loading the `libc` and using something like `libc.strcpy(imsi, tc.getIMSI())`

Answer (score 0):

ref to:[Using ctypes to write callbacks that pass-in pointer to pointer parameters to be used as output-parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786635/using-ctypes-to-write-callbacks-that-pass-in-pointer-to-pointer-parameters-to-be)

def like this : CFUNCTYPE(c_byte, POINTER(POINTER(c_char)))